# JFrame Close button

Tags: java, button, jframe, exit

I have a Jframe window inside which there is a button. By clicking the button it opens a new JFrame window. But when I close this window it automatically closes the first Jframe window with the button. How can I prevent the first Jframe window from closing when I close the second?

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Test");


        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                new SView().gui();
            }
        });


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        panel.setLayout(gridbag);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(156, 93, 82));
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: JFrames weren't made for doing this but rather to hold a single stable GUI. Also don't go swapping JFrames as that makes for a very bad user experience. You're much better off swapping views via a CardLayout or if you must show a dependent dialog window, then using a JDialog or JOptionPane.

Comment: I wish, but If I start changing around then its gonna get very messy. So is there not a way of preventing it then?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for more tips.
*"If I start changing around then its gonna get very messy."*  Don't worry.  It is already ***very messy.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call

```
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Would have been handy to mention calling `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`